# How do I enable execution of multiple jobs in parallel Hive

Tags: sql, performance, apache-spark, hive

I am running the below sql where the data in the table is around `4,34,836,959` records. It is taking more than 3 minutes to get the result.

```
select distinct col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5,  
to_date(concat(year(col_6),'-',month(col_6), '-1')) as col_6_new,col_7,
cast(first_value(col_11) over (partition by col_1,col_2,col_5,col_4,concat(year(col_6),'-',month(col_6)) order by col_6) as double) as col_9,
cast(first_value(col_11) over (partition by col_1,col_2,col_5,col_4,concat(year(col_6),'-',month(col_6)) order by col_6 desc) as double) as col_10,
min(to_date(concat(year(col_6),'-',month(col_6), '-1'))) over (partition by col_1,col_2,col_5,col_4) as col_8
from my_table
```

When I checked the execution from background, I could see that only 1 Job and 1 Stage is running at a time. Is there a way to parallelize this?

[image]

I even tried the below code, but Jobs/Stages are not running in parallel.

```
spark.sql("set hive.exec.parallel=true")
spark.sql("set hive.exec.parallel.thread.number=16")
spark.sql("set hive.vectorized.execution = true")
spark.sql("set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true")
```

The Spark version I am using is `2.3`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every stage in the Spark execution plan corresponds to the set of operations that **do not require shuffling**.

As far as I can see, you need at least 2 shuffles in your query:

1. For calculating window functions with clauses like `partition by col_1,col_2,col_5,col_4,concat(year(col_6),'-',month(col_6)) order by col_6`
2. For calculating final `distinct` operation.

Thus, 2 shuffles result in 3 Spark stages.

Since you cannot do `distinct` before calculating all window functions, the stages should be executed one by one and **cannot be parallelized**.
To check it from your side you can find the execution DAG in the Spark UI.